# Handle showing message on view close in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am working on an eclipse RCP application. The use case requires when I have 2 views opened and user tries to close one view then a message should be shown to user that second view will also be closed(just message and not confirmation).

This case works fine while I fire an event on dispose of first view to show message and close the second view. However if user exits the application/perspective or closes the application/perspective using close button at top right, I do not wish to show this message, rather just close the application/perspective along with the views.

I have tried to see if implementing ISaveablePart2 for for my would work, however I am unable to accomplish the requirement.

I have also tried sample from following link however again unable to address my use case.
[Handle the closing of the workbench window in Java RCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658927/handle-the-closing-of-the-workbench-window-in-java-rcp-application)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you trying to work out the reason that the first view is being closed?

Comment: The 2nd view shows some info which is related to first view. So when first view closes I wish to inform user that the second view will also be closed because the info it presents is stale. I hope I am able to explain it well now.